# Overlapping elements in OwlCarousel slider

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have a problem with my css here.
So I want to set up two owl carousels with images. My problem is that the image on top shall be in the foreground and it completely overlaps the image in the background, but it has transparent elements so you still see the image in the background. But because it overlaps the background image you cannot swipe on the background image with the owl carousel. I have tried several things with `z-index` but they did not really work out.
I provided a simple code snippet that illustrates my problem a little bit better. I want to keep the order of the elements regarding z-index, but you should be able to use the lower carousel slider as well. Any kind of help would be very appreciated.
Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   loop:true,
   items:1
   });
 });
```

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  background:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
.top{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1;
}
.top .img{
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
  text-align:center;
}
.bottom{
 position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom .img{
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div><div class="img">1</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">2</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">3</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div><div class="img">A</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">B</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">C</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute , fixed , or relative. Since you already have everything set you can just add z-index:2 to .bottom

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   loop:true,
   items:1
   });
 });
```

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  background:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
.top{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1;
}
.top .img{
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
  text-align:center;
}
.bottom{
 position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  z-index:2;
}
.bottom .img{
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div><div class="img">1</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">2</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">3</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div><div class="img">A</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">B</div></div>
      <div><div class="img">C</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```